# Parse text without delimiters using regex line by line

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract 5 fields from this sample log. I do not want to use delimiters, only regex.

How do I parse each line and extract the fields I want?

**Regex**

```
rx_dict = {
'date': re.compile(r'(?P<date>(\d+)[\/](\d+)[\/](\d+))'),
'time': re.compile(r'(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.(?:AM|PM))'),
'client': re.compile(r'(?P<client>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})'),
'flags': re.compile(r'(?P<flags>(?<=\].)(.{1,4}))'),
'query': re.compile(r'(?P<query>\s+([\S]*)$)'),
 }
```

**Sample Log**

```
4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 2604 PACKET  0000014DE1921330 UDP Rcv 192.168.1.28   f975   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)
4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 0574 PACKET  0000014DE18C4720 UDP Rcv 192.168.2.54    9c63   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)
```

Comment: What is your required output?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/DB8ufj/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and you are only interested in applying the regular expressions you have in your dictionary, then the following should get you started

```
import re

log = ["4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 2604 PACKET  0000014DE1921330 UDP Rcv 192.168.1.28   f975   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)",
       "4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 0574 PACKET  0000014DE18C4720 UDP R cv 192.168.2.54    9c63   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)"]

rx_dict = {
    'date': re.compile(r'(?P<date>(\d+)[\/](\d+)[\/](\d+))'),
    'time': re.compile(r'(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.(?:AM|PM))'),
    'client': re.compile(r'(?P<client>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})'),
    'flags': re.compile(r'(?P<flags>(?<=\].)(.{1,4}))'),
    'query': re.compile(r'(?P<query>\s+([\S]*)$)'),

for item in log:
    for key, r_exp in rx_dict.items():
        print(f"{key}: {r_exp.search(item).group(1)}")
    print()

Out:
date: 4/19/2020
time: 11:59:09 PM
client: 192.168.1.28
flags: A
query:       (7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)

date: 4/19/2020
time: 11:59:09 PM
client: 192.168.2.54
flags: A
query:       (2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use 1 pattern with [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get the groups, and omit unnecessary groupings from your patterns.

Instead of using a lookbehind `(?<=\].)` you could match the `]` char.

```
^(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+) (?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M).*? (?P<client>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*?] (?P<flags>.{1,4}).*? (?P<query>\S*)$
```

The separate parts look like

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)` Group *date*, match digits separated by `/` and space
- `(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)` Group *time*, match digits separated by `:` and AM or PM
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possible, then a space
- `(?P<client>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})` Group *client*, match ip like format
- `.*?]` Match any char as least as possible, then `]` and a space
- `(?P<flags>.{1,4}).*?` Group *flags* match 4 times any char except a newline and match a space
- `(?P<query>\S*)` Group *query* Match 0+ times a non whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J1k80M/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Dla3CP)

Example code

```
import re

regex = r"^(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+) (?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M).*? (?P<client>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*?] (?P<flags>.{1,4}).*? (?P<query>\S*)$"

test_str = ("4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 2604 PACKET  0000014DE1921330 UDP Rcv 192.168.1.28   f975   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)\n"
            "4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 0574 PACKET  0000014DE18C4720 UDP Rcv 192.168.2.54    9c63   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)")
print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.M))
```

Output

```
[('4/19/2020', '11:59:09 PM', '192.168.1.28', 'A   ', '(7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)'), ('4/19/2020', '11:59:09 PM', '192.168.2.54', 'A   ', '(2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)')]
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to do this with one regex pattern.  A bit too advanced for me right now. :-)